# Can I use custom filters with KOGrid?

Tags: knockout.js, kogrid

I have some custom filters, I could put them outside of the grid but it would look nicer if they were located at the same place as the built in one, can I somehow alter the filter template or in some other way alter the built in filter view?

This is the view I want to extend with custom filters

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started to implement this in a KoGrid fork, but the KoGrid template code is a bit complex, and I didnt have time to get it to work right now. So I did a little hack that does not alter the KoGrid source

http://jsfiddle.net/t23Ub/10/

```
(function() {
    function initGridTemplate() {
            var template = $(kg.defaultGridTemplate());
            var filter = template.find("div.kgColMenu > div[data-bind='visible: showFilter']");
        filter.attr("data-name", "config.filterOptions.model");
            filter.html("");

            kg.defaultGridTemplate = function () {
                return template[0].outerHTML;
            };
    }
    initGridTemplate();
}());
```

It works by adding a view model to the filterOptions literal. data-name in the above code is my framework that find views on viewmodels types, you could instead do

```
filter.attr("data-bind", "template: { name: config.filterOptions.templateName, data: config.filterOptions.model }");
```

This is what my data-name attribute is doing under the hood

Answer (score 2):

Currently the grid menu (filter view) does not have a custom/editable template.

It is part of the whole gird template: [gridTemplate.html](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/KoGrid/blob/master/src/templates/gridTemplate.html#L24-L41)

So currently the only option is to copy the `gridTemplate.html` and add your custom filter there and [configure](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/KoGrid/blob/master/koGrid-2.1.1.debug.js#L201) the KoGird to use your template with:

```
kg.defaultGridTemplate = function() {
  return 'your new grid template html';
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to fix context for custom filter viewmodel etc. I will change the source and pull it to the KoGrid

Comment: Yes, because KoGrid is an open source project you can always change it to fit your needs, but the current state is what I have in my answer. So if you want to have also a custom datacontext for your filter then there is no other option than to modify the source and introduce this feature.